# Parameter format not correct - flutter run

Tags: flutter

Even when I run a new project in my device or emulator, during Assemble debug process a message appears in Debug Console 'Parameter Format not correct', but the app seems to run properly.
when I add 1-2 dependencies/ plugins, countless redlines occurs in Debug Console... 
I don't know what is the reason and solution.

Answer (score 17):

Sorry guys this happens every time you run a project build by the previous version of flutter... and this error is not a big deal... dont worry...

Comment: Unfortunately this happens with brand new projects on the latest version of Flutter. Literally just installed Flutter and my first project got this error of `flutter run` .. as a dev, it baffles me how companies can release code with such huge bugs, where are the QAs?

Comment: I agree with @UndercoverCoder.

Answer (score 4):

I have also faced the same issue. It started coming when I upgraded the flutter SDK to `version 1.17.3`. The easiest solution I can come up with is to downgrade the flutter SDK.

If you are using VS code then you easily switch between flutter SDKs from the bottom bar.

To add flutter SDK -
Goto `file -> settings -> flutter SDK -> Add item`
then you can give the path of other SDK.

If you are not using the VS code, change the path of SDK from environment variables.

If this doesn't work out, try changing the drive for SDK of flutter and android both.
Example- From `D:\flutter` to `E:\flutter`. I have not tried this but for my friend, it worked.

If none of these workes, just ignore this error. They might fix this in future upgrades.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, but it was fixed by running  ***flutter doctor --android-licenses***

Comment: I've run " flutter doctor --android-licenses" ,then got "All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates..." but yet the problem didn't solve.

Comment: @abdullah_bd same thing happened to me

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue try to change Your Environment variable path

Answer (score 3):

it may be possible ,you have cloned the repo from github and trying to run on your local machine. just change the  compileSdkVersion in android>app>build.gradle file, i was facing this issue and get it fixed now
android {
compileSdkVersion 30
}

Comment: I don't have this entry to be changed. Where do I need to put it?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using VS Code, then you can try this process: Go to Settings -> Flutter SDK Paths -> click on Add Item. Then put the Flutter SDK location from your drive.
For example: C:\Flutter\flutter_windows_2.5.2-stable\flutter.
I hope it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, but it was fixed by running following command in terminal.

**flutter doctor --android-licenses**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sometimes You need to check the syntax in xml file inside android folder
example android/src/main/res/drawable/launch_background.xml and android/src/main/res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml